# Javascript - Access object from memory-cache

Tags: javascript

I'm working on an app for image editing. Each time an edit is made, the new version shows up in the network tab as a png.

I'm trying to add an "undo" feature which, to me, would mean using the previous version of the image.

So if the current version is the last image, I want the undo function to load the second to last. Is this possible?

I've been searching for ways to do this but haven't really seen anything that suggests it is.

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

[image]

### Update

I've been looking into this:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CacheStorage/keys

Comment: Doubt that would be possible

Comment: I don't think that is possible, but since you seem to use base64, a possible implementation would be to simply store the base64 text difference in a stack and push / pop to do / undo

Answer (score 0):

> So if the current version is the last image, I want the undo function to load the second to last. Is this possible?

Yes in general this is possible. That said the current approach isn't something I'd recommend doing as cache is persistence storage. You *could* store every edit as a base64 string and then when you want to undo call `array.pop()` and render the last element in that array. But this will quickly run into a problem that we could be storing *a lot* of long base64 strings as storage in the users web browser.

Instead there is a better way to do this is have a single `baseImage` and anything the users does instead keep track of the **operations** they did, and then simply do this in memory. Let's take an example such as Paint:

[image]

We could define this as a blank white `baseImage`. Followed by an array of three operations: `operations = [DrawRect, DrawLine, DrawCircle]` each of these could be thought of as an object that knows how to draw itself base on some points. An *undo* here would remove `DrawCircle` from the end then starting with the blank white image perform the `[DrawRect, DrawLine]` operations we saved in the array to end up with:

[image]

Some operations can be costly and eventually add up. We don't want to be starting from scratch and performing hundreds or thousands of operations the user did every time we undo. This is why many editors only have a set number of undo's you can do. What's happening here is we are changing our `baseImage` with our pervious operations and starting from there instead.

This can be considered a sort of buffer that we only hold so many operations. A simple way would be after say 20 operations when an undo is performed have it draw the first item and save that as the new `baseImage`. Although now this would be happening every operations after we pass 20. If the process for changing `baseImage` is an expensive one this could be staggered to say every 10 operations we remove the first 10 and save the image on the 10th operation instead. That way it makes it so we have at least 10 undo's available and we are also only changing `baseImage` every 10th operation.

I do want to point out for the most part this is me thinking out loud as I don't have any vast development experience in creating image editing or drawing software. Rather this is just an approach/concepts I'd take if I where to make one. Hopefully these points can help you make an undo feature that isn't too space/memory or computationally expensive.